# EC2 machine ubuntu reinstall

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 machine with ubuntu installed. I sort of messed up my apache configuration when I was trying to set up svn, so am having issues with apache. I want a fresh install of my machine with the same version of ubuntu. Is there any way to do that with the aws console other than creating a new ec2 machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the AWS console it will tell you what machine image you are using for that instance. You simply need to find that image again and boot a new instance based on that image.

When you launch the new instance it will ask you what image you want to use, just make sure to use the same one. That simple.